# Imports in python

Tags: python

i have this basic project structure

```
/components/__init__.py
/components/com_auth.py
/app.py
```

No! I want import some varible from **`app.py`** in `com_auth`.

I trying do like this

```
/components/__init__.py
/components/com_auth.py
/__init__.py
/app.py
```

But it, of course, not work.

Yes, i know, that i can do it like this

```
/app.py
/app/__init__.py                   <<<< there i containg varible
/app/components/__init__.py
/app/components/parent.py
/app/components/__init__.py
/app/components/com_auth.py
```

But how i can do it without it?

Comment: да мне лень переделывать около 40 файлов

Comment: If you downvote this or vote to close, please put an explaination (such as a duplicate link). Otherwise, this is a very common problem for Python beginers, so we should help him and not downvote.

Comment: It's quite clear, what he's asking. It's just very bad practice to do so. So why put on hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Don't do it! Whatever value you need to know from `app.py`, give it as a function argument to whatever you do in `com_auth.py`. Everything else will just mess up your program by running into circular dependencies sooner or later. Try to keep submodules as independent as possible.

Comment: I +1 this one, usually, you don't want to do this (importing somehting from an upper module). But this is not just about app.py. It will occurs with packages that are next to each others. The problem will be the same then. In that case, check my answer.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but isn't the main problem of the OP that he can't access anything from the `com_auth` module since they are in different folders?

Comment: He can do it with absolute imports, but it will only lead into further trouble and more questions about how to fix circular dependencies. So I guess it would be better to get it right from the beginning. For modules within the same folder, next to each other, the usual solution would be, to have another submodule within this folder, containing the common elements and importing from the new submodule.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a package, see the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

So something like:

```
yourpackage/                          # Top-level package
      __init__.py                     # Initialize the package
      app.py
      components/                     # Subpackage
              __init__.py
              com_auth.py
```

This then let's you access every module from everywhere within the package, for example like so:

```
from yourpackage.components import com_auth
from yourpackage import app
```

To use a variable from `app.py` in `com_auth`, you would rather import `com_auth` into your `app.py` file that then gives you access to the functions, classes etc from `com_auth` from within `app.py`:

```
from yourpackage.components import com_auth

i = 5
result = com_auth.yourfunction(i)
```

Comment: but that'd be complex and unnecessary for a simple program which involves about 3 scripts right?

Comment: Right, but if there are just 3 scripts, then you would probably just keep them in a single folder.

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that `app.py` is on your `PYTHON PATH`.

If you execute directly `python component/com_auth`, the upper directory is not in the `PYTHON PATH` (only the current script's dir is added automatically to the system `PYTHON PATH`), and thus upper modules such as `app.py` cannot be imported.

There are two solutions to your problem.

The quick and dirty one (still I use it when I'm lazy, it works well), it to manually add it to the `PYTHON PATH`:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

The proper solution, however, is to always make sure the point of entry of your program is at your top directory. Meaning `com_auth` should never be run directly, but always imported from a module from a module from a module... from the root. And there you run your code by doing `python point_of_entry.py` and never `python sub_module/any_other_module.py`. In your case, probably `app.py`.

In cases where it's not possible or desirable (admin commands, unit tests, etc), you should have a script with an option to add a directoy to the PYTHON PATH (this is what django-admin, nosetest, etc do).

I'm suspecting you are just testing your module, and only want to quickly run it. In that case, just enter :

```
PYTHONPATH='/path/to/your/project'
```

In your shell, and it will be added to your PYTHON PATH for the current session.

You can fixed up your architecture later.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to main file.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from app import var
```